# Best way to feature detect :focus-within pseudo-class

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I can't find any syntax using @supports that works with pseudo-class, except for `not` which is very specific to that pseudo-class.

What is the best way to detect if a browser supports focus-within, as I don't want to write a lot of browser hacks that will change in a few versions? I'm using Node and npm, but don't want to import a whole package for it (usually not the best way to handle things).

Trying to read the browser version string or use today's browser parsing hacks isn't a good idea because it will be difficult to maintain when browsers do start supporting a feature, so I'm looking for a feature detection method besides @supports. Is there a way to determine this in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it’s a pseudo class and therefor part of selectors, you would need the `@supports selector (…)` syntax here - but [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports#Browser_compatibility) for that specifically is not very good yet. (Basically just Firefox as of now.)

With some quick research I came across https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/2270 though - part of a discussion regarding implementing a test for this in the Modernizr library. User patrickkettner suggests the following JavaScript solution:

> Actually! There is a simpler way.
>
> `document.querySelector` throws on invalid selectors. You can just call `document.querySelector(':focus-within')` within a try-catch, if it doesn't throw it *should* be supported. We may find a browser that gives a false result, in which case we would need to actually test the style. However, in the mean time since it is a modern feature, we should be good with just that sniff test for now

Since this basic test still seems to be all Modernizer is doing in that regard currently (https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/focuswithin.js), I guess this should be safe to use.

Comment: Hmm, good to know. I've been using a few regexes against navigator.userAgent (browser detection instead of feature detection :/ ), but at face value this looks like a better alternative.